# VBA Excel Return value based on list

Tags: vba, excel

The VBA code below was supplied to us, and should make it possible to return streetaddresses based on the postcode and housenumbers we have in excel.

But I can't seem to get it to work at all. Mind I am not a VBA expert :(

I have the key and know it's needed. I have a column with postcodes, and a column with streetnumbers. I need to output a streetname for each of those lines.

Any idea how to set this up?

```
Sub gkkx()

Dim xDoc As Object
 Set xDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
 xDoc.async = False
 If xDoc.Load("https://api.pro6pp.nl/v1/autocomplete?auth_key=KEYGOESHERE&format=xml&pretty=True&nl_sixpp=" & Postcode & "&streetnumber=" & Streetnumber) Then
     If xDoc.DocumentElement.Text = "Not found" Then
     Plaats = ""
     Adres = ""
     Else
     If xDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Length = 0 Then
         Dim xDoc2 As Object
         Set xDoc2 = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
         xDoc2.async = False
         xDoc2.Load ("https://api.pro6pp.nl/v1/autocomplete?auth_key=KEYGOESHERE&format=xml&pretty=True&nl_sixpp=" & Left(Postcode, 4))
         Plaats = xDoc2.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("result/city").Text
         Adres = ""
         Set xDoc2 = Nothing
     Else
         Plaats = xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("results/result/city").Text
         Adres = xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("results/result/street").Text
     End If
    'If xDoc.documentElement.childNodes.length > 1 Then
    '    Tekst41 = MsgBox("Meerdere straten op deze Postcode", vbInformation, "Meerdere Straten")
    'End If
     End If
 Else
   ' The document failed to load.
    Plaats = ""
    Adres = ""
 End If
 Set xDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: The "key" probably goes where the code says `"KEYGOESHERE"`. Just a hunch.

Comment: *But I can't seem to get it to work at all*  -- voting to close as unclear what you're asking, please provide more detail about what specific failures you're experiencing. See [ask] and consider providing a [mcve].

Comment: I have typed KEYGOESHERE so yea. The question: I have a column with postcodes, and a column with streetnumbers. I need to output a streetname for each of those lines.

Comment: You've already indicated that in your question. What's the *actual, specific problem* with your implementation? Note: if you can't share the key, and if that website is not otherwise accessible to others, it may be very difficult to provide a useful answer.

Comment: You also may want to ask the person(s) who "supplied" the code why it is not working as you expect, they are probably better-prepared to answer such a specific question for your particular use-case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just glancing through your code and not doing any testing or really analyzing what it is supposed to do.  There are some code lines commented-out at the bottom section:

```
'If xDoc.documentElement.childNodes.length > 1 Then
'    Tekst41 = MsgBox("Meerdere straten op deze Postcode", vbInformation, "Meerdere Straten")
'End If
```

You may want to ask the code author if they intended this section of code to be left in as a comment - commenting-out code means the lines of code are ignored by the compiler.  Comments are created by prefixing any text with the apostrophe character.  Many times, when someone is writing code, they will comment out parts of the code so they can test individual sections of the code.  It could be that the author was doing this and forgot to un-comment (by deleting the apostrophes) this section of code.

Also, I would point out that this code appears to be working with Microsoft.XMLDOM.  To get a start on understanding what this code is doing, you may want to have a look [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468547.aspx).

It's probably not a total answer but I hope it helps.  It is a bit difficult, based on the brevity and vagueness of your question, to really have a picture of what you are trying to ask.